# Ajax image upload not working as expected

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to send an image via JavaScript after displaying the preview on the screen, I refuse to use Dropzone, Plupload or any JavaScript library, because I just want a simple functionality.

```
var finput;
var fileReader;
var fd; //formdata...

$(function(){
    fileReader = new FileReader;
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = fileReader.result;  //display the image on the screen...
        img.height = 200;
        $('#pimgbox').html(img);       
       //enable the image button... // $('#pimagebox').html(img);
       $('#pimgbtn').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled').removeClass('btn-alert').addClass('btn-primary');

    }
});
```

and when you click on the submit button

```
$('#pimgbtn').bind('click', function(e){   

    //initialize the formdata...

    fd = new FormData();    //initialize the formdata..
    fd.append('pimgupl', finput.files[0]);   //s
    //alert(fd);

    $('#pimgldr').css('display','block');
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-alert')
   
    if(fileReader.result != null){

////////////// beginning of ajax call...

         var settings = {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/user/setprofilepix",
                data: fd
            }; //end of setting..

            $.ajax(settings)
            .done(function (response) {
               alert(response);
               resetPUplButtons();
               //close modal...
               $('#profimgwin').modal('hide');
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                alert('error sending file...' + error);
                resetPUplButtons();
            });

      /////////////////////////end of ajax calls.. 

    }else{
        alert('you havent selected an image yet..');
        resetPUplButtons();
    }

});
```

and on my Laravel usercontroller I have this method that tries to upload the image but it's refusing to work.

```
 public function setProfilePix(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('pimgupl');
    $code = Auth::user()->profile->usrcode;
    $targetDir = public_path() . DS . 'userdata'.DS.'ppix';
    
    $newname = $targetDir.DS.strtolower($code).md5($code).'_'.time() .'.jpg';
   // echo $newname;
    //exit;
    $file->move($targetDir, $newname);

    echo 'saved';
}
```

I keep getting this error in my output panel:

[image]

Line 418 is the ajax operation, I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working. I have also added an exception to the route in my verifyCsrfToken.php - middleware, but still it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery try changing settings from

```
var settings = {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/user/setprofilepix",
                data: fd
            };
```

to

```
var settings = {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/user/setprofilepix",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
            };
```